# Перебрать ВСЕ свойства объёкта

Tags: javascript

Как можно получить такое же дерево свойств, как в DevTools? У `Map` есть свойство `size`, но его вообще ничего не берёт: ни `for..in`, ни `Reflect.getOwn`, ни `Object.getPropertyNames`. Мне нужно пройтись по всем свойствам: символы, `prototype` и `__proto__`, конструкторы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `[...new Map([['hello', 'world']]).entries()]`

Comment: @ΝNL993 Я не знаю, что я работаю с Map. Мне в функцию может прийти любой объект и я должен вернуть массив свойств объекта. Передавая в эту функцию экземпляр Map, я получаю пустой массив, хотя автодополнение предлагает size. Для свойств использовал `Reflect.getOwn`

Comment: Да я уже понял свою ошибку поэтому удалили комментарий...

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Map([['hello', 'world']]).__proto__)`, можно получить его методы, но вот значения... (технически это можно сделать используя метод `forEach`, который имеется во многих объектах, тот же `Array`, `NodeList` и т.п., но такой метод всё таки не у всех объектов и у остальных придётся через `Object.keys`)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Size не читается `Method get Map.prototype.size called on incompatible receiver #<Map> at get size [as size]`

Comment: getOwnPropertyNames чем не устраивает?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Прочитайте вопрос. У Map есть свойство size, но `getOwnPropertyNames` возвращает пустой массив